# How to add the Content Security Policy to load external JS files from CDN in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, express, content-security-policy

In ExpressJS, the HTML file is loaded as follows,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src/templates/'));
```

And in the HTML, this is my meta tag with Content Security Policy,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com kit.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; require-trusted-types-for 'script'; script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com">
```

I'm trying to load the following JS files from external sources,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4ff515084.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but I've specified them in the CSP meta tag, but still, I'm getting the following error and the external JS files are not getting loaded.

[image: console error]

and I can see some issues,

[image: console issues]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Content Security Policies at the same time:

1. the first one through `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">`
2. the second one is published by Helmet 4 (it has [default CSP](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide#there-is-now-a-default-policy) enabled).

Directive rules from multiple CSPs are combine with logical "AND" therefore more restrictive CSP is acts.

Use Helmet to configure CSP HTTP header (preferred way), or use meta tag, bot not both at the same time.